# по каким критериям понять, что посетитель - бот?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Пишу онлайн-калькулятор на `php`, который берет прайс-листы из БД `mysql`. Форма с `ajax` отправляет запрос на сервер при изменении любого поля. Столкнулся проблемой: на хостинге стоит лимит на количество запросов к БД в час, а разнообразные пауки иногда накликивают этот лимит.

Как лучше поступить:

- разбираться на этапе формирования запроса, делать ajax запрос или нет,
- или смотреть в заголовки с помощью php?

На какие заголовки обращать внимание?

---

небольшой оффтоп в тему: запросы `SELECT SQL_CACHE ...` - считаются полноценным "запросом к БД" в смысле лимита на подключения, установленного на хостинге?

Comment: для начала я бы порекомендовал ознакомиться с таким явлением, как `robots.txt`.

Comment: я не хочу эти страницы закрывать от роботов, я хочу отключить ajax для роботов.

Comment: я не уверен, но скорее всего они никакого яваскрипта не поддерживают. или жизнь идет и все меняется? :)

Comment: Тогда не обрабатывайте ajax запросы от пользователей у которых в юзерагенте присутствуют 'bot', 'spider' или 'crawler' ;)

Comment: @toxxxa, в первую очередь я подразумевал скрипты.

Comment: @splash58, кажется, меняется: https://moz.com/blog/just-how-smart-are-search-robots

Comment: @splash58 не всем это надо, но js можно заводить в эмуляторе браузера. Selenium например умеет.

Comment: да, это усложняет проверки. у меня где-то на сайте до сих пор скрытая переменная заполняется в форме через js, как признак не робота :)))

Comment: к слову: [кэширование](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.caching.php) запросов не поможет?

Comment: Об этом была вторая часть вопроса. SELECT SQL_CACHE будет считаться как запрос к базе?

Comment: Не поможет, кэшированный запрос просто отдастся из буфера. Соединение все равно устанавливается

Comment: не проще сделать какое то скрытое поле, и проверять его на пустоту,в случае если оно заполненное то не выполнять запрос, в случае если оно пустое - выполнять аякс